# Serving static files from Python alpine image: no /etc/mine.types file found

Tags: python, django, docker

I have an Python Django application that I want to deploy through docker-compose, I used the blogpost called [A Production-ready Dockerfile for Your Python/Django App](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2017/03/14/production-ready-dockerfile-your-python-django-app/) to setup my files.

This blogpost, however, assumes you use a third party to host your static files. Since this isn't the case, I changed the `CMD` command from:

`CMD ["/venv/bin/uwsgi", "--http-auto-chunked", "--http-keepalive"]`

to:

`CMD ["/venv/bin/uwsgi", "--http-auto-chunked", "--http-keepalive", "--static-map", "/static=/code/base/static"]`

This works more or less, I now however receive the following warning when I start my docker file:
`backend_1        | !!! no /etc/mime.types file found !!!`

This makes my solution not workable, since files are all interpreted as `text/plain`. Is there a simple solution to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `mailcap` package in your alpine container. Add the below to `Dockerfile`

```
RUN apk add mailcap
```

Comment: It had to be `RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual mailcap` but now it works, thanks!

Comment: yes because there is no cache. Either you run a `apk update` and then the command or `apk add --no-cache --virtual mailcap` like you did